# Effective MySQL database backup

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I'm using mysql 5.7.27 version and by default database is InnoDB.

I wanted to take the backup of the MySQL database.

Below are my findings.

1] mysqldump -u[user] -p[password] --single-transaction --routines --all-databases > [DBbackup.sql]

2] mysqldump -u[user] -p[Password] [database_name] > [DBbackup.sql]

I didn't understand the actual use of --single-transaction.
I'm very new to MySQL please suggest if there are any best options of mysqldump command to take effective backup

Comment: In case any application that uses your DB works with transactions (I.e. BEGIN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK) , then using `--single-transaction` flag will ensure all the tables are in consistent state transaction-wise.

Comment: Is this a live database?

Comment: Yes it is live DB which under use